# SQL Reporting Services - Using a single .rdl file with parameters

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have been using SQL Report Builder 3.0 and Reporting Services to publish reports for the last 8 months. Still somewhat of a novice but slowly figuring out how to work with this amazing toolset more efficiently. I have started using parameter driven reports and all going well. However one question that I am struggling to get answer for is whether it is possible to use a single .rdl file and then use parameters to generate the required reports at runtime.

Currently, I have a setup a .rdl file that uses parameters and an existing stored procedure (via data source) to feed data to the report. What I do each time is open the .rdl and save it as a report with a new parameter. This means that if I need to make a change to the report in any way, then I have to redo the setup for each report. It feels that this is very inefficient and was wondering if there is a way to reuse a single .rdl file and setup up multiple runtime reports off this single .rdl file?

Any guidance would be hugely appreciated.

Update: Just to clarify further. The report is used to report on client transactional data. So each time a new client is added to the business I create a new RDL for that specific client. Exactly the same RDL file but saved as a new name, and with a new parameter being the Client code

Comment: Why aren't you using a SQL Server BIDS project file with multiple reports (RDL) files in it and just redeploy the reports that changed?

Comment: When you say, "What I do each time is ..."  Each time what?

Comment: Thanks Benjamin - have only SQL Report Builder 3.0 to date. Will try using BI Dev Studio

Comment: @Tab - The report is used to report on client transactional data. So each time a new client is added to the business I create a new RDL for that specific client. Exactly the same RDL file but saved as a new name, and with a new parameter being the Client code

Answer (score 3):

Use the Client Code as a parameter in Dataset to get data for that client.Now call the report passing the Client Code as parameter. You can see the parameters of datasets in Parameters section under Report Data Menu.
Report Data->Parameters->your parameters

You can call your report as follows:

url of the report at reportserver?parameter=Client Code

I have been working on SSRS reporting since last 6 months. I think this might work for your case.